# With MEF, can I cause a method to run before any types are exported?

Tags: .net, mef

Is there a way in MEF to have one of my methods run before any types are exported?

I'm using MEF in assembly A, and some of the types I'm using are in another assembly (B). Assembly B is stored inside the resources of assembly A (part of code obfuscation), so I need to handle `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event so I can load assembly B.

So I'd like to be able tell MEF to run method X (which will handle that event) before exporting any types. At the moment, I need to add code to all the constructors of the exported types, and avoid using any types from assembly B in the wrong place (i.e. if they would be resolved before the `AssemblyResolve` event has been handled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the host, you can run code before you do any composition.

It sounds like you are trying to do this in an extension and the host doesn't have any knowledge of the obfuscation, though.  MEF doesn't have anything explicitly to support this.  You could do something like use a custom export attribute for all of your exports, and put code in the export attribute's constructor that ensures that assembly B is loaded.  This is going against what Export attributes are supposed to do-- they are supposed to just supply metadata and not actually run code which does anything.  However, it might work for you.

Another thing that worries me is that as an extension you are hooking into AppDomain.AssemblyResolve.  I think that only one handler for the event will be used, so if the host or any other extensions want to hook into this behavior, it won't work for everyone.